# Add raw string macro using target_compile_definitions

Tags: c++, cmake, rawstring

I want to add to `CMakeLists.txt` raw string macro equivalent of:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
#define COMMPORT_NAME R"(\\.\COM1)"
#elif defined(Q_OS_UNIX)
#define COMMPORT_NAME "/dev/ttyS0"
#else
#error "platform not supported"
#endif
```

I tried the following:

```
if(WIN32)
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -DCOMMPORT_NAME="R"(\\.\COM1)"")
elseif(UNIX)
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -DCOMMPORT_NAME="/dev/ttyS0")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "platform not supported")
endif()
```

But I get an error:

> CMake Warning (dev) at path/to/project/CMakeLists.txt:68:
>     Syntax Warning in cmake code at column 85
>
> Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
>   This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Is it possible to use some kind of quotes, like '' in bash to prevent occurrence of the above error?

Comment: Seems it is nonsense, because it leads to more work. I think I just should to use `"\\\\.\\COM1"`.

Comment: For CMake double quotes (`"`) is a special symbol. If you want to pass it to underline system, you need to escape it: `\"`. Note, that passing string to a **macro** (as opposite to a function) consumes one level of escaping.